# With a flex box containing one image and one line of text, how can I set the width of the box and text automatically based on teh size of the img?

Tags: html, css

Given the following:

```html
<style>
.img_box {
    display: flex;
}
</style>

<div class=img_box>
    <img src=img/>
    <div>Title text of some variable length. Can sometimes be wider than the image, sometimes smaller</div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to set either a height or width value on the image and have the box shrink to match so it's the same width as the image (minus padding or whatever). The text should wrap and not affect the width of the box at all so whatever the image is sets the width for the box and text.

I know the height of the box will stretch to accommodate wrapped text and that's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already use `display: flex` in your `.img_box` class, you can easily achieve this by setting `flex-direction: column` and `width: min-content`. Finally, give the image a desired `width`.

```css
.img_box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; 
    width: min-content;
}

.img_box img {
    width: 200px;
}

.img_box div {
    text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div class="img_box">
    <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/lego/1.jpg" alt="Test Image">
    <div>Title text of some variable length. Can sometimes be wider than the image, sometimes smaller</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yup! I got a bit rusty and didn't remember how to solve it or apparently find the other similar answers (I swear I looked!). Thank you!